# Push calculated result from one array to another using loops

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop, while-loop

I am trying to figure out how to push the result from the array to the empty arrays after using a function to calculate the result, using a for loop and another with a while loop but I don't understand what I am doing wrong. This is part of The Complete JavaScript Course 2021: From Zero to Expert! on udemy. I would really appreciate if someone could help me understand this.

```
function percentageOfWorld1(population) {
  const worldPopulation = 7900;
  return (population / worldPopulation) * 100;
}

let populations = [1441, 4, 6, 8];
const percentages2 = [];
const percentages3 = [];

while (populations < populations.length) {
  populations++;
  percentages2.push(percentageOfWorld1(populations));
}

for (let i = 0; i < populations.length; i++) {
  percentages3.push(percentageOfWorld1(i));
}

console.log(percentages2);
console.log(percentages3);
```

Expected results is the calculated percentage of the world population for each of the 4 numbers in the populations array pushed in to its respective array.

result I got for the first one percentages3: script.js:179 (4) [0, 0.012658227848101267, 0.025316455696202535, 0.0379746835443038]

the result I got for percentages2 was an empty array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the same result in both loops, then your mistake was, that you were looking if populations(array) is smaller than its length.
You need to declare a new int variable and then add +1 to the int and not to the array.

Additionally, the for loop adds +1 after the code inside the loop is done, so in the while loop you need to add +1 at the end. look in the snippet I added

```js
function percentageOfWorld1(population) {
  const worldPopulation = 7900;
  return (population / worldPopulation) * 100;
}

let populations = [1441, 4, 6, 8];
const percentages2 = [];
const percentages3 = [];

let n = 0;
while (n < populations.length) {
  percentages2.push(percentageOfWorld1(populations[n]));
  n++;
}

for (let i = 0; i < populations.length; i++) {
  percentages3.push(percentageOfWorld1(populations[i]));
}

console.log(percentages2);
console.log(percentages3);
```

EDIT:
You want to pass the 4 values of the 'populations'array right?
Then you need to pass the integer n or i in the array --> populations[i]

Another alternative, you can use this for the for loop:

```
for (let i of populations) {
    percentages3.push(percentageOfWorld1(i));
}
```

this is the same as the for loop in the snippet, just try it out :)

Comment: I see thank you, but why is it calculating the first result in each array to be 0, that is also something I could not figure out.

Comment: It is because, you start with the value 0, therefore if you pass 0 to your function, it results 0/7900 * 100, which always results 0 :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but how do you avoid that and make it calculate the actually number of index 0 in the array that is 1441?

Comment: now I understand what you mean, I was also a bit confused tbh, well then you need to pass the element of the index you declared, so instead of passing n or i, you pass populations[n or i], which means you pass the n-index of populations

Comment: I added also another compact and better way for a for loop at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

From your code:

```
let populations = [1441, 4, 6, 8];
populations++;
```

`++` is an operator used for numbers, not arrays. To make an operation on every array element, you need to iterate / "loop" on them. Also:

```
percentages2.push(percentageOfWorld1(populations));
```

`populations` here is an array, while your `percentageOfWorld1` function expects a number. Shouldn't you provide `populations[i]` element instead? Learn more about [Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). Using a while loop.

```
let i = 0;
while(i < populations.length) {
    percentages2.push(percentageOfWorld1(populations[i]));
    i++;
}
```

The more common beginner way is using a for loop, as you have tried with `percentages3`. You need to provide populations[i] instead of i. Practice and check the differences.

Note: the functional equivalent would be :

```
percentages2 = populations.map(percentageOfWorld1);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, a lot to wrap my head around, I will need to really take my time to understand this.